# How would I sent user to new "block" instead of continue same path?

Tags: python, text, skip

```
response = ""
while response not in directions_window:
    print("While crouched below the window you begin weighing you options")
    print("You decide your only options are to listen in, knock on window, or wait")
    response = input("Which are you doing?\nlisten/knock/wait")
    if response == "listen":
        print("You raise your head slightly to hear better\n")
        print("You can ony make out a few words before the figure inside sees you\n")
        print("Latin words can be heard screaming as it charges towards the window\n")
        print("You try to run away, but slip and fall on your stomach.\n")
        print("The figure catches up to you only to knock you unconsious.\n")
        print("You wake up with scratches and marks around your wrist\n")
        print("Taking in your surroundings, you notice you're at the entrance to the forest.\n")
        print("You cut your losses, and leave the forest. Forever wondering who, or what, that was.\n")
        quit()
```

I'm in the process of making a text-based adventure game. I want to send the user to a new "part" of the game if this option is selected instead of quit(). How would I skip to a new block? Also, I know I can write it without print every line, but I wrote this over time as ideas came to me. Will fix later

Comment: What does "skip" to a new "block" mean? be a bit more verbose. have you checked out how control flow statements work in python? (if else, for loops, etc)

Comment: meaning If i want to branch paths depending on what the user chooses. if a is chosen send to this code. if b is chosen send to this other code.

Answer (score 1):

What you might be looking for is to use functions to branch your adventure's "path" into different "sections" which each direct the user to a different area (and can even loop the user back to an area they were before if desired), like this:

```py
def adventure_listen():
    print("you picked listen")
    # ... more text
    response = input("Which do you pick?\nA/B")
    if response == "A":
        do_something()
    elif response == "B":
        do_something_else()

def adventure_knock():
    # code similar to above

def adventure_wait():
    # code similar to above

print("message1")
response = input("Which are you doing?\nlisten/knock/wait")
if response == "listen":
    adventure_listen()
elif response == "knock":
    adventure_knock()
elif response == "wait":
    adventure_wait()
```

Comment: I thought of using functions in this way, but wasn't sure what I would need to write to send the user to a specific branch instead of continuing to the next line of code which would be for a different branch.

Answer (score 0):

"Jumping blocks" as you call it, is something that is used in assembler code. In high level languages (such as python), flow control structures are used (if else, for loops, while, etc).

For your specific case, if you decide to use flow control structures, and your *story* is long you will sooner than later get lost in your own code. Functions, as proposed by Cristopher Rybicki, would be a better way to go. For this you should either (a) first know your story in advance and/or (b) find a common structure or pattern in your story that allows you to "open" and "close" chapters.

(a) because it will help you structure better your code
(b) because if you cannot draw at first your story it will help you keep a structure and follow some patterns.

Execution of code is sequential, so you (*cannot*) **should not** "jump" from one function to another avoiding (or hoping to) the code after some "branch" line not to execute.

The more advanced approach (and the one I would recommend), is to go with classes and learn your way through inheritance. So your program could have `Actions`, `Moves` or whatever you choose it to have. Because you might now want to `adventure_knock`, and later it might be `adventure_throw_the_door_down`. They both (i) come from another step in the story, (ii) will have a feedback given to the user, and (iii) will have to go back to a point in the story.

in your main execution you can have a loop that initiates your `stories`, `chapters`?, and so on.

a **pseudocode** example would be:

```
Action:
    abstract function start_action:
        ...
    abstract function end_action:
        ...
    abstract function give_feedback:
        ...
    function ask_for_input:
        input('What are you waiting for?')

Knock extends Action:
    function start_action:
        #specific implementation of knock...
    ...
```

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. This helps me out a ton. Thanks!